# What does "as popular as it has ever been" mean?

Tags: meaning, as

> It is as popular today as it has ever been.

What does it mean by "as popular as it has ever been"?

1. The level of popularity today is the same as the one in the past when it was the highest.
2. The level of popularity today is the same as it always has been.

or something else? I am not sure what it means exactly and I can't find it in any dictionary.

Comment: *Literally*, it's normally the second meaning, but *idiomatically*, the general construction *X is as Y as it's ever been* (where X is a noun and Y is an adjective) often implies *X is **at least** as Y now as at any time in the past, **and possibly more so***. That and/or speaker is robustly refuting any suggestion that X might be ***less X*** today than it was in the past (often, speaker is denying any suggestion that X is *in decline*, or losing some quality represented by Y).

Comment: wow thank you so much. Very clearly explained. thank you thank you